# Can I mod my phone with bootloader locked?

Tags: bootloader, motorola-defy, motorola

I have a Motorola Defy ('jordan') that I have just recently rooted. I would like to add a mod to it though as it is running on Android froyo still but my bootloader is locked so i'm not very sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are not sure about anything... goto XDA forums.It has everything

Comment: If your bootloader is locked, and if there isn't an unlock available, you are probably stuck on your current android version/ROM. Root alone doesn't let you update the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the Defy's bootloader is locked, you can still root it and install custom roms. It's with the help of a software called 2ndInit.

As mentioned in the comment, you can search in the xda forums to get the details. You can [start here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=853672) by rooting and then install any custom rom. :)